# "dictionary changed size during iteration" while updating a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I have a list of dictionaries, which looks like this:

```
car_list = [
    {'Toyota': '{name}/Toyota'},
    {'Mazda':  '{name}/Mazda'},
    {'Nissan': '{name}/Nissan'}
]
```

Now, using a regex, I want to replace all `{name}`s with another string (say "`car`"), and update the list of dictionaries. This is the code:

```
regex = r'\{.+?\}'
for dic in car_list:
    for key, value in dic.items():
        for name in re.findall(regex, value):
            value = value.replace(name, "car")
        dic.update(key=value)
```

I know as a fact that the regex part is working. However, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.update(key=value)` inserts a new key into the dictionary where the key is *the string literal* `'key'` and value `value` (as assigned in the line above).

You should use brackets to index into the dictionary, rather than calling `.update()`:

```py
for dic in car_list:
    for key, value in dic.items():
        for name in re.findall(regex, value):
            value = value.replace(name, "car")
        dic[key]=value

# Prints [{'Toyota': 'car/Toyota'}, {'Mazda': 'car/Mazda'}, {'Nissan': 'car/Nissan'}]
print(car_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a regex - `str` has two built-in methods, `format` and `format_map`, to replace fields marked with curly brackets, like your sample code:

```py
msg = "Hello, {location}!"
print(msg.format(location="World"))

msg2 = "{greeting}, {place}!"
params = {"greeting": "Bonjour", "place": "Birmingham"}
print(msg2.format_map(params))
```

Using this:

```py
for dct in car_list:
    for key, value in dct.items():
        dct[key] = value.format(name="car")
```